# Linq to Entities using incorrect parameters

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have been working on this for almost 9 hours now and just don't understand what is going on.  I have created an Advanced Query Builder that allows the user to add parts to their where clause.  My plan was to take advantage of the deferred execution.  The problem is that I kept getting 0 as my count for things I knew had records.  What made this more puzzling was it only occurred if I had more than 1 query.  Because I can't give you my data model and all my code, I have summed this up and here is a basic code sample:

```
        string foo = "smith";
        var result = context.claims.AsQueryable();
        var temp = from p in result
                   where p.Prescription.Patient.last_name.Contains(foo)
                   select p;
        foo = "jo";
        temp = from p in temp
               where p.Prescription.Patient.first_name.Contains(foo)
               select p;
        int count = temp.Count();
```

Now, my expectation is that this would give me a query that returned results where patient's last name is like '%smith%' and first name like '%jo%'.  However here is the query that is executed:

```
    exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM     [dbo].[claim] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Prescription] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[prescriptionId] = [Extent2].[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Patient] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[patient_id] = [Extent3].[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Prescription] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[prescriptionId] = [Extent4].[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Patient] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[patient_id] = [Extent5].[id]
    WHERE ([Extent3].[last_name] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N''~'') AND ([Extent5].[first_name] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE N''~'')
)  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000)',**@p__linq__0=N'%jo%',@p__linq__1=N'%jo%**'
```

As you can see by the query that was executed, I did not get the intended results.  Instead it set both parameters on the linq query to what the last value of the variable was set to.

Can someone please explain why this is happening?  I found a workaround but it is not pretty.  I have to declare a variable for each of the possible columns and set that variable = to the value then use that variable in the linq statement:

```
        string foo = "smith", foo2 = "jo";
        var result = context.claims.AsQueryable();
        var temp = from p in result
                   where p.Prescription.Patient.last_name.Contains(foo)
                   select p;
        temp = from p in temp
               where p.Prescription.Patient.first_name.Contains(foo2)
               select p;
        int count = temp.Count();
```

Comment: Because the execution is deferred, the query expression is not translated until you actually enumerate results (`Count()`). At that moment, the value of `foo` is "jo".

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Wiktor!!  Well that makes sense, but it sure does cause issues with my logic!!  I can't believe I couldn't find anyone else who has seen this.

Comment: After ten minutes you found @WiktorZychla, who had seen it. What's "not pretty" about having two different strings as two different strings?

Comment: The problem with having 2 strings is that in the real world I would like to have N number of columns to search by and I was trying to create a function that would dynamically add the clauses.  However, if I have to know how many clauses there are then it makes it less dynamic and more hard coded.

Comment: With the approach you're taking with one block of code after another, you have to know that anyway so you write out that many blocks. With real code you'd either want some sort of enumerable, list, array etc, or make multiple calls to a function that just added one, so you won't have the problem.

Comment: Oh wait. Was this proof of concept? Are you really going to re-use foo in the same scope in the same call?

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = result.Count(x=> x.Prescription.Patient.last_name.Contains(foo) && 
                             x.Prescription.Patient.first_name.Contains(foo2));
```

or

```
var result = (from p in result
              where (p.Prescription.Patient.last_name.Contains(foo) && 
                     p.Prescription.Patient.first_name.Contains(foo2))
              select p).Count();
```

Also take a look at using [PredicateBuidler](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to dynamically compose expression predicates. It can be useful if you need to build up a complex query dynamically that mixes && and ||.